# How to float containers inside absolute positioning box?

Tags: css

Here are two cases:

Expected behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2eR/7/

Inconsistent behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2eR/1/

How can I make the second example work like the first one and why is this difference?

## Conclusion

I set up a fix width for the parent.
Using absolute position with body as the parent is really tricky ( when you get to the edges )

Comment: They render the same in my browser (FF 3.6, Mac). The only difference is the `left` parameter in CSS. Is that intentional?

Comment: I don't see a difference, except one is 800px to he left and the other 900px.

Comment: Probably because of the resolution, i put a lower value and update the links. Hope you can see it now.

Comment: The difference is the left value left:100px; and how the containers f1 and f2 float. ( The desire behavior is to stay on the same line)

Comment: There seems to be no difference for me using Chrome...

Comment: There is still no difference. But I think I know what you are going for: floats are wrapping in one and aren't in the other. This is an important lesson in explaining problems: Don't say "they are different". You **have** to explicitly say what difference you see, and what you are expecting to see. Not everyone see the same "inconsistencies" just because you do, because there is no "inconsistency" - this is how floats work.

Comment: @RoToRa but why they are wrapping in the second and not in the first one ?

Comment: @danip: Try resizing the window. Once the second float is "outside" the width of the window it wraps - consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simplify your code. All you need to do is set the float:left; for the inner elements and the positioning in the parent element. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2eR/30/

```
#menu {
 border: 1px solid red;
 position:absolute;
 left:100px;   
}
.inner{
 border:1px solid black;
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
}
```

The reason your code didn't work is because the left:800px was so big it the inner elements didn't have any room to float into. This can be fixed by setting a *width* or by ensuring that the *left* adjustment has enough room to float into.

Comment: Read my answer again: "_This can be fixed by setting a width or by ensuring that the left adjustment has enough room to float into._"

In other words you need to set a lower left value or set a width. That's the only way this is going to work using position:absolute. If setting a lower left value isn't an option try replacing it with a right tag with a lower value: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2eR/33/

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    left:900px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    width:24px;
}
```

give the #menu div some fixed width, if it's possible

Comment: it's not posible for fix width

Answer (score 0):

how about not floating the internal divs, but instead making them inline-blocks, would that work for your use case?

#### example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/zbkdq/) here

if this works you will need a small workaround for IE7 and below, and will somehow need to give IE the rule `#menu div {display: inline;}` **after** the inline-block rule